# Prove that there is no solution in terms of elementary functions of $y'=x^2+y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have seen before that

$$y'=x^2+y^2$$

Has no solution in terms of elementary functions. I typed it in on Wolfram Alpha ([here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=e602dcdecb1843943960b5197efd3f2a)) and got a giant solution with a bunch of Bessel functions that I did not understand. This equation is almost like a Ricatti equation, but not exactly, so there may be some insight to be gained there. Again, my question is:

*How do you prove that this differential equation has no solution in terms of elementary functions?*

Answer (score 5):

It *is* a particular case of the Riccati equation.

Set $\displaystyle y=-\frac{f'}{f}$, then $\displaystyle y'=-\frac{f''}{f}+\frac{f'^2}{f^2}$, so that the equation for $f$ is given by
$$f''+x^2f=0.$$
This is *linear* and solvable in terms of Bessel functions:
$$f(x)=C_+\sqrt{x}\,J_{\frac14}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)+C_-\sqrt{x}\,J_{-\frac14}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right).$$
The answer given by Wolfram Alpha is nothing but the logarithmic derivative of this formula. Note that only the ratio $C_{+}/C_-$ will appear in the expression for $y$, providing the integration constant for the initial 1st order equation.

---

Bessel functions $J_{\pm\frac14}(z)$ can also be expressed in terms of parabolic cylinder functions as indicated [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.16.E3), but do not simplify further.

Comment: I wonder if this answers the OP's question: does the fact that solutions can be written in terms of Bessel functions imply that they cannot be rewritten in terms of elementary functions (in this particular equation, at least)? How does one prove that?

Comment: @AlexM. Have you seen my P.S.? NIST digital library does not have simpler expressions for $J_{\pm\frac14}(x)$ (and in fact it is known that Bessel functions reduce to elementary ones only for half-integer values of parameters). Now if one wonders how this can be formulated in terms of, say, differential Galois theory, the OP should first give the rigorous definition of "elementary" (liouvillian? non-transcendental in the sense of Umemura theory? ...?) I suspect however that the question was more elementary.